# Time of completion of last Postgres Checkpoint

Tags: postgresql

Is there a `psql` way to get the completion time (and other details) for latest Postgres checkpoint?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the details of the latest checkpoint, including the time, from the `pg_control_checkpoint()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_control_checkpoint() \gx

─[ RECORD 1 ]────────┬─────────────────────────
checkpoint_lsn       │ B/AF0C2EB8
redo_lsn             │ B/AF0C2E80
redo_wal_file        │ 000000040000000B000000AF
timeline_id          │ 4
prev_timeline_id     │ 4
full_page_writes     │ t
next_xid             │ 0:16691338
next_oid             │ 559103
next_multixact_id    │ 16340004
next_multi_offset    │ 326571432
oldest_xid           │ 726
oldest_xid_dbid      │ 1
oldest_active_xid    │ 16691338
oldest_multi_xid     │ 1
oldest_multi_dbid    │ 1
oldest_commit_ts_xid │ 0
newest_commit_ts_xid │ 0
checkpoint_time      │ 2022-05-23 08:18:02+02
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable [log_checkpoints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CHECKPOINTS) then any checkpoint will be written to the server's log file.

This will result in log messages like this:

```
checkpoint complete: wrote 0 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.010 s, sync=0.001 s, total=0.132 s; sync files=0, longest=0.000 s, average=0.000 s; distance=0 kB, estimate=1303 kB
```

(the above was a forced checkpoint on an idle test system)

So you can't access that information from within `psql`, you need access to the server's file system to read the logfile.

If you really need to access that from within `psql` you can either use `pg_read_file()` to read it's content or expose the log file as a foreign table through [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html)